# U2F integration with multiple FacetIDs without Chrome Extension but u2f-api.js

Tags: fido-u2f, yubico

I try to implement U2F into my web application. Since the application is available with more than one URL, I have to add a JSON file with valid FacetIDs as described in the [spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-ps-20141009/fido-appid-and-facets-ps-20141009.html#determining-if-a-caller-s-facetid-is-authorized-for-an-appid). Yubico has a shorter summary of that spec on their [website](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/App_ID.html).

Unfortunatly, when I call the `u2f.register(...)` Method, I get the error code 2, which means that there is a problem with the AppID.

My AppID is the URL to the JSON file. As described in the spec, I add `application/fido.trusted-apps+json` as content type. Anyway, this URL is never called.

I'm using the newest Chrome (v46.0.2490.80m). As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164770/849507) the Chrome Extension is not necessary anymore.

Furthermore I found a closed [Bug Report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471522) on the Chromium Project which tells me that U2F is implemented according to the Specs.

Instead of the Chrome Extension I'm using the [u2f-api.js](https://demo.yubico.com/js/u2f-api.js).

Is this u2f-api.js the problem? Is there a newer one?

This is my code so far:

```
var u2frequest =
[
    {
        "appId":"https://localhost:44300/api/u2f/appids.json",
        "challenge":"hDharTG-SROuScxyD7ACpMDp4xl6A91E9nUPXDRSo_4",
        "version":"U2F_V2"
    }
];
u2f.register(u2frequest, [], function (data) {
    // I always get data={errorCode:2} here.
}
```

Comment: did you solve this, Michael? If so, would you please post the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @LesNightingill I'm afraid not yet.

Comment: I can see one problem with your code... but maybe you've fixed it already as it has been a while... The arguments list for u2f.register should be(appId,registerRequests,registeredKeys,callback_function). You don't have appId in your args.

Comment: Did you actually get https working on localhost?

Comment: Any update on if you ever got this working? Same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Facets will not work with self signed certificates. So single identity application will work just fine on localhost, but multiple identifies will not work on localhost.

Best solution is to rent a VPS and get Letsencrypt certs.

Comment: May be this the solution

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have different origins in your appId json, the origin of facetID must be the same as AppID, 
for example: all facetID in https://example.com/app-id.json must have the same origin of https://*.example.com

so in your case your trustFaceID should all belong to https://localhost:44300

Comment: Where do you see that in the spec?

Comment: @kspearrin https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.1-id-20160915/fido-appid-and-facets-v1.1-id-20160915.html#appid-example-1